# PowerAutomate + SharePoint List - When an item is created - Multiple items created immediately and single instance noticed leading to issues

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a SharePoint list **"ComputerAccessServices"**. I have a power automate cloud flow which triggers on **"When an item is created"** on the mentioned SharePoint list. The flow has loops and conditions.

[image]

**Now Testing:**

**Scenario 1**: Creating multiple items in the list after a minute or so. The flow works perfectly fine. Each new item created after a minute or so triggers a new instance of the flow. As expected.
[image]

**Scenario 2**: Creating multiple items in the list but right immediately after the first one was created. Basically, created one item in the list and then created second item immediately in the same list. This triggered only one instance of the flow and the data in the loops all messed up. This one flow is running for two items that was created. Is there something I'm missing when the trigger "When an item is created" is run? I'm really stuck with this issue as it can lead to big time data manipulation and wrong details captured in the flow and lists.

**Flow**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect your issue is with your handling of multiple items, correct? If so, why not just change it to handle multiple items at once? It leading to “big time data manipulation”, etc. isn’t a problem with the product, it’s a problem with your implementation. Show us your flow so we can get a better idea.

Comment: start and wait for approval flow goes into wait until first item is approved. the approval for second item waits until action is taken on the first item. the approval for second approval should go out as well. This works fine when items are created between gaps of more than 30seconds or a minute. some how the trigger only starts one run for two items created immediately right after the other.

Comment: Show us your flow, paste an image into your question.

Comment: @Skin i have added the flow diagram.

Comment: Are the FOR EACH actions running over the data from the trigger?  If the answer is YES, are your FOR EACH actions running sequentially or in parallel?  i.e. what is the concurrency setting set to?

Comment: Only "For Each 6", "For Each 4", "For Each 1" and "For Each" are running over data from the trigger.

"Apply to each" is running from "InitializeApprovers" variable.

"For Each 3", "For Each 2" and "For Each 5" are running from response from "Start and wait for an approval".

All loops and connectors are running sequentially, and "Concurrency Control"->"Limit" is set to "Off".

Comment: Managed to figure this issue out. It's the trigger that needs to be set to "Settings"->"General"->"Split On"->"On". This ensures that multiple items added to the list at once splits the entries into multiple runs instead of just one run.

Comment: I was going to help you work with multiple items without the split but whatever works. One thing to note in future, variables are global and loops will run concurrently unless you turn them off, ie set concurrency to 1. If you set variables in loops that run concurrently, you’ll get unintended behavior. So my point is, although you’ve “fixed” your issue, there are things you need to understand in order to make sure your resulting workflow is robust. Look at using compose in loops instead if you want concurrency. Good luck!

Comment: @skin, happy to learn your method without the split option. Still open to the best way forward or any alternatives to the split. please do share when ready.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this issue out. It's the trigger that needs to be set to "Settings"->"General"->"Split On"->"On". This ensures that multiple items added to the list at once splits the entries into multiple runs instead of just one run. Had to remove the loops which took the output from the "When item is created". Now the connectors are taking trigger output values.

Hope this will help someone save some time. I have struggled for few days trying to understand the settings and behavior of the flow.

[image]